# Is it possible in Angular to display a value in an option but return an array to the ngModelChange?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I am trying to organize a drop down list that will display a single value to the user but will also pass back an array object upon changing the selection.

Currently I have an array called classificationresult that has 3 elements CLASSIFICATION_NAME, GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME.

When a user selects a particular CLASSIFICATION_NAME I want to pass back the entire array result containing all 3 elements listed above.

Currently the code below works for everything EXCEPT showing the CLASSIFICATION_NAME in the drop-down box upon loading. It shows the list once you click, but it starts with a blank until it is clicked. Any way to fix this? I believe the display element is tied to [ngValue] but that is also what I am using to pass back the entire array versus just the one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<p>Select Classification*</p>
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedClassification (ngModelChange)="changedClassification($event)">
<option *ngFor="let classificationresult of classificationresults" [ngValue]="classificationresult" >{{ classificationresult.CLASSIFICATION_NAME }}</option>
</select>
```

**Summary** -- I want my drop down list to always have a value shown to the user (value being the Classification Name) but when one is selected I want the entire array to pass to the changedClassification function. Also sometimes after a user selects from other drops down on this page they will also go blank, but if they are selected a second time they will populate.

Comment: If you have the data already within the component, why not just filtered the data and convert it into the array within `ngModelChange`?

Comment: This helped me solve it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working as you are expecting *except* the initial value being displayed, I wonder if you need a `[compareWith]` function. I don't know what your `classificationresult` model looks like, but if I had to take a guess, putting a `[compareWith]` function on your `<select>` element would fix the issue.

[Here is an article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c) explaining it a little more.

I made [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9umtns) as an example with using the `[compareWith]` function. In my demo I am using ReactiveForms, but the `compareWith` should still be the same.

For your code, it may look something like:

```html
<p>Select Classification*</p>
  <!-- add this [compareWith] -->
  <select [compareWith]="myCompareFunc" [(ngModel)]="selectedClassification" (ngModelChange)="changedClassification($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let classificationresult of classificationresults" [ngValue]="classificationresult" >{{ classificationresult.CLASSIFICATION_NAME }}</option>
</select>
```

In your **.ts** file:

```js
export class YourComponent {
  // all your component code.. 

  /* compare function, change the logic to fit your needs */
  myCompareFunc (classificationRes1: any, classificationRes2: any): boolean {
    return classificationRes1 && classificationRes2 
      ? classificationRes1.CLASSIFICATION_NAME === classificationRes2.CLASSIFICATION_NAME
      : classificationRes1 === classificationRes2
  }
}
```

If that doesn't fix your issue, you may need to post more of your **.ts** code and data models.